# Linux : Shell scripting to known whether it is evening or morning

Tags: linux, shell

My code is giving error . I think there is error in line 1.

```
x=$((date+"%H"))
printf "%d\n" $x

if [ $x -le 12 ] 
then
printf "GOOD MORNING\n" 
elif [ $x -le 16 ] 
then 
printf "GOOD AFTERNOON\n"
else 
printf "GOOD EVENING\n"
fi
```

thanks

Answer (score 5):

`$(( ))` evaluates mathematical expressions, and `date +"%H"` is not a maths expression. I think you may be confusing it with `x=$(date +"%H")`, which is "assign the output of `date +"%H"` to `x`.